# How to calculate multiple results of Vcmax from ACc-curves in R?

Tags: r

I have plenty of ACc-curves data with CO2 concentration change or PAR change of different leafs.
  I want to do some data processing to get Vcmax and Jmax parameters. I got the packages of plantecophys. It can export the parameters i want, but i dont know how to fit many curves at once with fitaci {plantecophys}.
  And is there any other packages can fit ACc-curves and get the Vcmax, Jmax parameters.
  Thany you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fitacis` function which provide a option to subset your data with a group vairable. The documentation [here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plantecophys/versions/1.1-8/topics/fitacis) should be useful.